# JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data when attempting to fetch data from php

Tags: php, reactjs

This is my React code used for checking log in information:

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

let fData = new FormData();

const checkLogin = async () => {
    await fetch("http://localhost/innovate_recipe/Backend/VerifyLogin.php/", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: fData,
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
};

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    checkLogin();
    fData.append('Username', username);
    fData.append('Password', password);
    console.log(fData);
};
```

And this is my php file for processing fetch request:

```
session_start();
include 'DbConnect.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With");

$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $password, $database);


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['Username']) && isset($_POST['Password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['Username'];
        $password = $_POST['Password'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username='$username' and Password='$password'";
        $result =  mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            echo json_encode($username);
        } else {
            echo json_encode("Wrong username or password");
        }
}
```

fData would return a proper object and I would get the error when I submit the form. If I remove the if statement to check if the Username and the Password is set, and change res.json() to res.text(), I would get the error:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "Username" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\innovate_recipe\Backend\VerifyLogin.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "Password" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\innovate_recipe\Backend\VerifyLogin.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
"Wrong username or password"
```

How could I resolve the error?
Thank you.

Comment: In `handleSubmit`, why do you set the form-data __after__ sending the request?

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',` doesn't make any sense. You're not sending JSON, you're sending a FormData object which will either translate to form-url-encoded or multipart-formdata format. So you're just confusing the server with the misleading content-type, which surely can't be helping. But yeah, it's also quite obvious that you don't even put anything into `fData` until you've already sent it to the server! Look at the sequence of your code in the `handleSubmit` function.

Comment: There is also an SQL injection vulnerability in this code, as POST parameters are being inserted directly into the SQL code.  I strongly suggest you adapt it to use a prepared statement and bound parameters instead.

Comment: Your PHP code is also insecure. You **must** a) use prepared statements and parameters to prevent SQL injection and SQL syntax errors , b) use password hashing to securely store the passwords without them being stealable. Please urgently read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords and act accordingly. Even if this is only a practice project, you should get into good habits and learn useful techniques, not insecure ones.

Comment: Thank you @RobEyre and ADyson for pointing out bad practices in my code. I've read the posts you provided and used prepared statements as well as password hash.

Comment: Thank you @tkausl and Adyson for spotting out the wrong logic in my code. The code is running now.